# Detecting a GameObject Between Two Point

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I Have Two Point And List Of Gameobjects and I need to Khow Which one of them is between those two point Can You Help me?

[image: pic]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use LineCast between two points

```
 Vector3 p1;
 Vector3 p2;
 RaycastHit2D h = Physics2D.Linecast(p1, p2);
 Debug.Log(h.collider.name);
```

Comment: thanks about your answer i will mark that as a answer but is RaycastHit2D can detect more than one gameobject?

Comment: So if I Use RaycastHit2D and there are two Gameobject on the way witch one will return?

Comment: the first one it hits